# Efficient Signed Multiplier with good timing

Tags: vhdl, pipeline, fpga, vlsi

> I am making a signed multiplier for that i have created half adder,
>   full adder,
>       ripple carry adder and then finally a multiplier. The code is shown below. How can i make it faster to achieve better timing. My
>   final task is to make a fir filter operating running at 100Mhz. This
>   filter use multiple multiplication operation(by using my multiplier).
>   So Can you help me to make my design better by some optimizing
>   technique like pipelining or parallelism or other??

```
   //half adder
    entity half_adder is
    port (
    a, b : in std_logic ;
    sum, cout : out std_logic );
    end half_adder;

    architecture version1 of half_adder is
    begin
    sum <= a xor b;
    cout <= a and b;
    end version1;
```

> -- full adder

```
    entity full_adder is

    port(

    a       : in  std_logic; 
    b       : in  std_logic; 
    cin     : in  std_logic; 
    sum    : out  std_logic; 
    cout    : out  std_logic
    );
    end full_adder;


    architecture structural of full_adder is
    component half_adder
    port (
    a, b : in std_logic ;
    sum, cout : out std_logic );
    end component;
    signal s1, c1, c2 : std_logic ;
    begin -- structural
    half_adder1 : half_adder
    port map (
    a => a, b => b,
    sum => s1, cout => c1);
    half_adder2 : half_adder
    port map (
    a =>cin, b => s1,
    sum => sum, cout => c2);
    cout <= c1 or c2;

    end structural ;
```

> -- ripple carry adder 40 bit

```
    entity rca40bit is
  generic (
          width: integer := 40
          );
    port(
        a         :    in  std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
        b         :    in  std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
        cin     :    in  std_logic;
        sum     :    out std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
        cout     :    out std_logic
        );
    end rca40bit;

architecture Behavioral of rca40bit is
component full_adder 
port(

    a       : in  std_logic; 
    b       : in  std_logic; 
    cin     : in  std_logic; 
    sum    : out  std_logic; 
    cout    : out  std_logic
    );
    end component;
    signal s: std_logic_vector(width downto 0);

    begin
    s(0)<=cin; 
    FA:for i in 0 to width-1 generate
    FA_i:full_adder 
    port map 
    (
    a=>a(i),b=>b(i),cin=>s(i),sum=>sum(i),cout=>s(i+1)
    );

    end generate;

    cout<=s(width);

    end Behavioral;
```

> -- Multiplier,i calculated partial products first then add them by rca adder.

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;


    entity signed_mult is
    generic (

          m   : integer := 24;    -- Multiplicand

          n   : integer := 16 ; -- multiplier;

         bit1 :integer := 39      -- size of the adder

          );


    port(

        a         :    in    std_logic_vector(m - 1 downto 0)      ;
        b         :    in    std_logic_vector(n - 1 downto 0)      ;
        prod      :    out   std_logic_vector(bit1 downto 0)

        );
    end entity signed_mult;

    architecture Behavioral of signed_mult is


component rca40bit 

 port(
                  a         :    in  std_logic_vector(bit1 downto 0);
                  b         :    in  std_logic_vector(bit1 downto 0);
                  cin       :    in  std_logic;
                  sum       :    out std_logic_vector(bit1 downto 0);
                  cout      :    out std_logic
                );




     end component;

--partial products signals 

     signal p0 : std_logic_vector(bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0') ;  --1st 
    `enter code here`partial product size m-1 bits (24 bit)
    signal p1: std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0'); --2nd 
      partial product size m bits (25 bit) 
    signal p2 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');  --3rd partial 
    product size m+1 bits (26 bit)  
    signal p3 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');  --4th partial 
    product size m+2 bits (27 bit)  
    signal p4 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');   --5th 
    partial product size m+3 bits (28 bit)
    signal p5 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');   --6th 
    partial product size m+4 bits (29 bit)
    signal p6 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');   --7th 
    partial product size m+5 bits (30 bit)
    signal p7 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');   --8th 
    partial product size m+6 bits (31 bit)
    signal p8 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');   --9th 
    partial product size m+7 bits (32 bit)
    signal p9 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');  --10th 
    partial product size m+8 bits (33 bit)
    signal p10 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');   --11th 
    partial product size m+9 bits (34 bit)
    signal p11 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');  --12th 
    partial product size m+10 bits (35 bit)
    signal p12 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');   --13th 
    partial product size m+11 bits (36 bit)
    signal p13 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');   --14th 
       partial product size m+12 bits (37 bit)
    signal p14 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');   --15th 
      partial product size m+13 bits (38 bit)
     signal p15 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0);   --16th partial product 
             size m+14 bits (39 bit)
     signal p16 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0);
     signal p17 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0');   



    signal extc0 :std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0) ;




--constants and  carry


 signal  zeros :std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0) :=(others =>'0');
 signal c : std_logic := '0' ; 
 signal c0 : std_logic :='0' ; 
  signal c12 : std_logic :='0' ; 
 signal c23 : std_logic :='0' ; 
 signal c34 ,c45,c56,c67,c78,c89,c910,c1011,c1112,c1213,c1314,c1415,c1516 ,c1617: std_logic := '0'; 
  signal c15 : std_logic_vector (bit1 downto 0):=(others =>'0'); 


 --sum only


    signal sum12 : std_logic_vector   (bit1 downto 0); 
    signal sum23 : std_logic_vector   (bit1 downto 0); 

   signal sum34, sum45,sum56,sum67,sum78, 
   sum89,sum910,sum1011,sum1112,sum1213,sum1314,sum1415,sum1516,sum1617,ps0: 
   std_logic_vector   (bit1 downto 0);


 --signal f_sum: std_logic_vector   (bit1 downto 0);   --sum of p0 and P1
 --signal tpp1 : std_logic_vector   (bit1 downto 0); 



 begin 

pp0: process is 
begin 
 fst_partial_product :for i in 0 to m-1 loop  -- 0 to 23


p0(i)<= (a(i) and b(0)) ; 


if i=m-1 then 

p0(i)<=not ( a(i) and b(0)); --msb=m=24

end if ;
 end loop  fst_partial_product ;



n2d_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop -- 24

 p1(0)<='0';
 p1(i+1)<=a(i) and b(1) ;

if i=m-1 then 
p1(i+1)<=not (a(i) and b(1)); --msb=m=24


 end if ;
 end loop n2d_partial_product;


r3d_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop

p2(0)<='0';
p2(1)<='0';
p2(i+2)<=a(i) and b(2) ;
if  i=m-1 then
p2(i+2)<=not( a(i) and b(2)); --msb=25

 end if ;
 end loop r3d_partial_product;

r4th_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop
p3(0)<='0';
p3(1)<='0';
p3(2)<='0';
p3(i+3)<=a(i) and b(3);
 if i=m-1 then 
p3(i+3)<=not(  a(i) and b(3)); --msb=26

end if ;
end loop r4th_partial_product;

r5d_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop

p4(0)<='0';
p4(1)<='0';
p4(2)<='0';
p4(3)<='0';
p4(i+4)<=a(i) and b(4) ;
if i=m-1 then 
p4(i+4)<=not( a(i) and b(4)); --msb=27
end if ;
end loop r5d_partial_product;

t6hpartial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop
p5(0)<='0';
p5(1)<='0';
p5(2)<='0';
p5(3)<='0';
p5(4)<='0';
p5(i+5)<=a(i) and b(5) ;
if i=m-1 then 
p5(i+5)<=not( a(i) and b(5)); --msb28

end if;
end loop t6hpartial_product ;

t7h_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop

p6(0)<='0';
p6(1)<='0';
p6(2)<='0';
p6(3)<='0';
p6(4)<='0';
p6(5)<='0';
p6(i+6)<=a(i) and b(6) ;
if i=m-1 then 
p6(i+6)<=not (a(i) and b(6)); --msb=29
end if;
end loop t7h_partial_product;

t8th_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop
p7(0)<='0';
p7(1)<='0';
p7(2)<='0';
p7(3)<='0';
p7(4)<='0';
p7(5)<='0';
p7(6)<='0';
p7(i+7)<=a(i) and b(7) ;
if i=m-1 then 
p7(i+7)<=not( a(i) and b(7)); --msb=30

end if;
end loop t8th_partial_product ;


t9th_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop

p8(0)<='0';
p8(1)<='0';
p8(2)<='0';
p8(3)<='0';
p8(4)<='0';
p8(5)<='0';
p8(6)<='0';
p8(7)<='0';
p8(i+8)<=a(i) and b(8); 
if i=m-1 then
p8(i+8)<=not( a(i) and b(8)); --msb=31
end if;
end loop t9th_partial_product;

t10th_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop
p9(0)<='0';
p9(1)<='0';
p9(2)<='0';
p9(3)<='0';
p9(4)<='0';
p9(5)<='0';
p9(6)<='0';
p9(7)<='0';
p9(8)<='0';
p9(i+9)<=a(i) and b(9) ;
if i=m-1 then
 p9(i+9)<=not( a(i) and b(9)); --msb=32

end if;
end loop t10th_partial_product ;

t11th_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop

p10(0)<='0';
p10(1)<='0';
p10(2)<='0';
p10(3)<='0';
p10(4)<='0';
p10(5)<='0';
p10(6)<='0';
p10(7)<='0';
p10(8)<='0';
p10(9)<='0';
p10(i+10)<=a(i) and b(10) ;
if i=m-1 then
p10(i+10)<=not( a(i) and b(10)); --msb=31

end if;
end loop t11th_partial_product;

t12th_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop

p11(0)<='0';
p11(1)<='0';
p11(2)<='0';
p11(3)<='0';
p11(4)<='0';
p11(5)<='0';
p11(6)<='0';
p11(7)<='0';
p11(8)<='0';
p11(9)<='0';
p11(10)<='0';
p11(i+11)<=a(i) and b(11) ;
if i=m-1 then
 p11(i+11)<=not( a(i) and b(11)); --msb=32

end if;
end loop t12th_partial_product;
t13th_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop

p12(0)<='0';
p12(1)<='0';
p12(2)<='0';
p12(3)<='0';
p12(4)<='0';
p12(5)<='0';
p12(6)<='0';
p12(7)<='0';
p12(8)<='0';
p12(9)<='0';
p12(10)<='0';
p12(11)<='0';

p12(i+12)<=a(i) and b(12) ;
if i=m-1 then
 p12(i+12)<=not( a(i) and b(12)); --msb=32

end if;
end loop t13th_partial_product ;
t14th_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop

p13(0)<='0';
p13(1)<='0';
p13(2)<='0';
p13(3)<='0';
p13(4)<='0';
p13(5)<='0';
p13(6)<='0';
p13(7)<='0';
p13(8)<='0';
p13(9)<='0';
p13(10)<='0';
p13(11)<='0';
p13(12)<='0';
p13(i+13)<=a(i) and b(13) ;
if i=m-1 then
 p13(i+13)<=not( a(i) and b(13)); --msb=32
end if;
end loop t14th_partial_product ;
t15th_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop

p14(0)<='0';
p14(1)<='0';
p14(2)<='0';
p14(3)<='0';
p14(4)<='0';
p14(5)<='0';
p14(6)<='0';
p14(7)<='0';
p14(8)<='0';
p14(9)<='0';
p14(10)<='0';
p14(11)<='0';
p14(12)<='0';
p14(13)<='0';
p14(14)<='0';
p14(i+14)<=a(i) and b(14) ;

if i=m-1 then 

p14(i+14)<=not( a(i) and b(14)); --msb=32
end if;
end loop t15th_partial_product;

t16th_partial_product : for i in 0 to m-1 loop

p15(0)<='0';
p15(1)<='0';
p15(2)<='0';
p15(3)<='0';
p15(4)<='0';
p15(5)<='0';
p15(6)<='0';
p15(7)<='0';
p15(8)<='0';
p15(9)<='0';
p15(10)<='0';
p15(11)<='0';
p15(12)<='0';
p15(13)<='0';
p15(14)<='0';
p15(i+15)<=not (a(i) and b(15)) ;


if i=m-1 then 
 p15(i+15)<= (a(i) and b(15));

end if;



end loop t16th_partial_product ;


wait on a,b;
end process pp0;

p16(39)<='1';
p16(38 downto 0)<=p15(38 downto 0);
--sum 

extc0(39 downto 0 )<=zeros(39 downto 24) & '1' & zeros(22 downto 0 ); -- just store 1 on msb of 1st pp
c15(39 downto 0 )<=zeros(39 downto 16) & '1' &  zeros(14 downto 0 )  ; -- just store 1 on msb of 1st pp



--sum temp p0
tmp1st_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>extc0 , b=>p0, cin=>c, sum=>ps0 ,cout=>c0); ---carry + p0
--sum temp p0
--ttmp1st_pp:rca40bit 
--port map(a=>extc0 , b=>p0, cin=>c, sum=>ps1 ,cout=>c0); ---carry + p0


--sum  1st and 2nd row of pp
s1tnd_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>ps0 , b=>p1, cin=>c, sum=>sum12 ,cout=>c12);

--adding sum of s12   and 3rd row of pp

t3rd_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum12, b=>p2, cin=>c, sum=>sum23 ,cout=>c23);

--adding sum of s23   and 4rt row of pp

t4rh_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum23, b=>p3, cin=>c, sum=>sum34 ,cout=>c34);


t5rh_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum34, b=>p4, cin=>c, sum=>sum45 ,cout=>c45);

t6rh_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum45, b=>p5, cin=>c, sum=>sum56 ,cout=>c56);


t7th_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum56, b=>p6, cin=>c, sum=>sum67 ,cout=>c67);


t8th_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum67, b=>p7, cin=>c, sum=>sum78 ,cout=>c78);

t9th_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum78, b=>p8, cin=>c, sum=>sum89 ,cout=>c89);

t10th_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum89, b=>p9, cin=>c, sum=>sum910 ,cout=>c910);

t11th_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum910, b=>p10, cin=>c, sum=>sum1011 ,cout=>c1011);

t12th_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum1011, b=>p11, cin=>c, sum=>sum1112 ,cout=>c1112);

t13th_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum1112, b=>p12, cin=>c, sum=>sum1213 ,cout=>c1213);

t14th_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum1213, b=>p13, cin=>c, sum=>sum1314 ,cout=>c1314);

t15th_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum1314, b=>p14, cin=>c, sum=>sum1415,cout=>c1415);

carryaddwith15th_pp:rca40bit 
port map(a=>sum1415, b=>p16, cin=>c, sum=>sum1516,cout=>c1617);

t16th_pp:rca40bit 

port map(a=>c15, b=>sum1516, cin=>c, sum=>sum1617,cout=>c1516);

 prod <=sum1617;



 end Behavioral;
```

> **Filter Design**

```
library IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity your_filter is
    Generic (
        constant PIPELINE_DEPTH   : positive := 2;
        constant DATA_WIDTH       : positive := 24;
        constant FIR_ORDER        : positive := 34;
        constant COEFF_WIDTH      : positive := 16      
    );
    Port ( 
        clk           : in  STD_LOGIC;
        rst           : in  STD_LOGIC;
        data_in       : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        data_out      : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0)
    );
end your_filter;

architecture Behavioral of your_filter is



component ripple_ca is
port(
       a         :    in  std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH+COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
       b         :    in  std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH+COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
       cin     :    in  std_logic;
       sum     :    out std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH+COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
       cout     :    out std_logic
);
end component;

component signed_mult is
 port(

       a         :    in    std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0)      ;
       b         :    in    std_logic_vector(COEFF_WIDTH - 1 downto 0)      ;
       prod      :    out   std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH+COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0)

       );

end component;

        type REG_TYPE is array (0 to FIR_ORDER-1) of signed (DATA_WIDTH+COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        type COEFF_ARRAY_TYPE is array (0 to FIR_ORDER) of signed(COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0);

        type REG_TYPE2 is array (0 to FIR_ORDER-1) of std_logic_vector (DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        type sum is array (0 to FIR_ORDER) of std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH+COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0); 
        signal sum1 : sum;
        signal c1 : std_logic;
        signal c : std_logic :='0';
         type COEFF_ARRAY1 is array (0 to FIR_ORDER) of std_logic_vector(COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0); 
        signal coeff : COEFF_ARRAY1;
        signal reg          : REG_TYPE2;
        signal next_reg     : REG_TYPE2;
        signal reg1          : REG_TYPE2; 
        type REG_TYPE1 is array (0 to FIR_ORDER-1) of std_logic_vector (DATA_WIDTH+COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        signal next_reg1     : REG_TYPE1; 
        signal data_out_temp       : std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH+COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        signal tempmult : sum;
        signal  data_in_reg       :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        signal  next_data_out      :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);



        constant coeff_array : COEFF_ARRAY_TYPE := (
        "0000000101011111",
        "0000000001100001",
        "0000000000110011",
        "1111111111011010",
        "1111111101011111",
        "1111111011011001",
        "1111111001100101",
        "1111111000100101",
        "1111111000111011",
        "1111111010111111",
        "1111111110111001",
        "0000000100100000",
        "0000001011011000",
        "0000010010110011",
        "0000011001111010",
        "0000011111110010",
        "0000100011101011",
        "0000100101000010",
        "0000100011101011",
        "0000011111110010",
        "0000011001111010",
        "0000010010110011",
        "0000001011011000",
        "0000000100100000",
        "1111111110111001",
        "1111111010111111",
        "1111111000111011",
        "1111111000100101",
        "1111111001100101",
        "1111111011011001",
        "1111111101011111",
        "1111111111011010",
        "0000000000110011",
        "0000000001100001",
        "0000000101011111"  
                                                    );

begin



    --synchronous process
    sync_proc : process (clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if rst = '0' then
                reg             <= (others=>(others=>'0'));
                data_in_reg     <= (others=>'0'); 
                data_out        <= (others=>'0');
             else
                reg             <= next_reg;
                data_in_reg     <= data_in;
                data_out        <= next_data_out;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    --asynchronous process
    async_proc : process (reg, data_in_reg)
        variable sum : signed(DATA_WIDTH+COEFF_WIDTH-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    begin
       for i in 0 to FIR_ORDER -2 loop
           next_reg(i+1) <= reg(i);
                  end loop;
           next_reg(0) <= (data_in_reg);

--      data_out_temp <= std_logic_vector(sum + signed(data_in_reg)*coeff_array(0));--std_logic_vector(sum);--(sum);--

for i in 0 to FIR_ORDER-1 loop
        coeff(i)<= std_logic_vector (coeff_array(i));
        reg1(i)<= std_logic_vector (reg(i));
        --next_reg1(i)<= std_logic_vector (next_reg(i));
     end loop;
coeff(FIR_ORDER)<= std_logic_vector (coeff_array(FIR_ORDER));


end process;

  --next_reg(i) <= reg(i+1)+(signed(data_in_reg))*coeff_array(i+1);
  nextreg :   for i in 0 to FIR_ORDER -1 generate

       accumumlator : signed_mult
          port map ( a => reg1(i), b => coeff(i+1), prod => tempmult(i) );          
     end generate nextreg;

     sum1(0) <= (others => '0');
     addition :   for i in 0 to FIR_ORDER -1 generate
     addition01 : ripple_ca
               port map ( a => sum1(i),b => tempmult(i) , cin=>c, sum => sum1(i+1),cout => c1 );
end generate  addition;
    -- data_out_temp <= std_logic_vector(reg(0) + signed(data_in_reg)*coeff_array(0));--std_logic_vector(sum);--(sum);--

      dataout : signed_mult
       port map (

       a => data_in_reg,
       b => coeff(0),
       prod => tempmult(FIR_ORDER)
       );

  addition_2 : ripple_ca
   port map (a => sum1(FIR_ORDER),b => tempmult(FIR_ORDER) ,cin=>c , sum => data_out_temp ,cout => c1);                         


        next_data_out <= data_out_temp(DATA_WIDTH+COEFF_WIDTH-1  downto COEFF_WIDTH);


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Is this an academic exercise? usually the fastest results come from using the dedicated multipliers on the chip.
In your code, how do you expect to get any FMax without a clock?

Comment: You current method *"I have created half adder, full adder...."* does not match with your target *good timing*. For fast result you should not build your own adder/multipliers but let the synthesis tool handle it.

Comment: @Tricky yes it is an academic exercise. The timing constraint file .xdc i hv not uploaded but it generates 10ns clock which means 100MHz..

Comment: @Oldfart My course subject is advanced vlsi whose requirement is to make fast components by students not by synthesis.

Comment: But your design has no clock - so it wont matter whats in the XDC file, as you have nothing to time.

Comment: The code doesn't analyze,  has comments spanning new lines and missing context clauses. The question *"So Can you help me to make my design better by some optimizing technique like pipelining or parallelism or other??"* appears [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). What synthesis tool, target device or primitive library and technology, and paths violating constraints? Off hand shortening adders to n bit will require a lot less synthesis effort. Show your assignment requirements. What has been done so far to identitfy and address the problem?

Comment: @Tricky Filter Code is added now, you can see the clk usage.

Comment: @user1155120 The filter code is added here. In that, Multiplication of data_in with coefficient array is done for  34 times. My design requirement is to operate filter at 100MHz. Currently i am getting -33ns slack. I need to improve my design.Itcould be multiplier design or filter design.

Comment: You need to put more pipelining in. Basically, break up your multiply. Or for a much better >200Mhz result, use the embedded multiplier.

Comment: @Tricky yes you are saying right. I need more pipelining. But I am not aware of pipelining code and concept. Can you help me with pipelining??

Comment: @Tricky where in my code can i put pipelines.

Comment: @ZohaibRamzan Pipelining involves putting registers between sections of logic. Your code involves one big logic cloud. You need to break it into smaller sections. While this may increase latency, clock speed can be increased by more than enough to compensate for the latency.